# How to create a HOC component in react validated with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I have a HOC component that currently just passes through children:

```
import * as React from "react";

interface Props {
    children?: any
}

function BaseWidget(props: Props) {
    const { children } = props;

    return (
        <div>
        {children}
        </div>
    );
}

export default BaseWidget;
```

Then I have another component that I want to wrap with the above component like a HOC.

So I have tried this:

```
function MockWidget(props: Props) {
    const classes = useStyles(props);

    return (
        <List className={classes.root}>
        {mockPosts.map( (post: Post) => 
            <ListItem alignItems="flex-start">
                <ListItemAvatar>
                    <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src={post.img} />
                </ListItemAvatar>
                <ListItemText
                primary={post.channel}
                secondary={
                    <React.Fragment>
                    <Typography component="span" className={classes.inline} color="textPrimary">
                        {post.name}
                    </Typography>
                    {` — ${post.message}`}
                    </React.Fragment>
                }
                />
            </ListItem>  
        )}
      </List>
    );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
    root: {
        width: '100%',
        maxWidth: 360,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
      },
      inline: {
        display: 'inline',
      },
}));

export default withBaseWidget(MockWidget);
```

However I got an error in the withBaseWidget() definition:

```
function MockWidget(props: Props): JSX.Element
Type '(props: Props) => Element' has no properties in common with type 'Props'.
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: How is `withBaseWidget` defined in your code? It looks like you are just importing `BaseWidget` and calling it `withBaseWidget`...

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a proper HOC wrapper, just like you would in JS.

Given `BaseWidget` and `MockWidget`:

```
function withBaseWidget<P>(WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>) {
  return (props: P) => {
    return <BaseWidget><WrappedComponent { ...props } /></BaseWidget>;
  }
}
```